# Makehuman rigged model appear all purple in weight paint mode

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, makehuman

When I click on my rigged character(mhx rig) from Makehuman in **Blender's** weight paint mode, it's all shown in purple. I can't see weights of any of my bones.

I am not sure what's happening here. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen on a few models I've come across, but its an easy fix.

To see the weight paint, you need to unhide and select the deformation bones which are tucked away in *Object Data* under *Skeleton - Layers*. Ignore the *Protected Layers* bit.

[image: Skeleton panel]

I don't have a MakeHuman model handy, but this pic shows where the deformation bones are for both Rigify and Pitchipoy, labeled with a DEF- prefix. Keep in mind that you may no be able to move DEF bones directly, so keep the both this layer and the bone control layer active (holding *Shift* and click on the layer).

Both these rigs also have hide/unhide buttons for all the different parts at the *Properties Panel*, not sure if yours will also have it.It works the same as above only that the buttons have names for the part they are assigned to.

[image: panel2]